# Any good rulesets that are gritty, dark, and low-magic?

Tags: game-recommendation, campaign-settings

I am currently making a world setting for my group of players and I was hoping for recommendations for any ruleset that is

- Low-Magic - A hint of magic known to those who are born into special bloodlines or spend their lieftime to learn the little they can, and bonus points if the magic can have a consequence if done improperly.
- Dark - The players are in constant danger, and doing that idiotic thing the voice in their head is telling them to do will probably get them in serious trouble if not dead.
  Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Unfortunately as described in the game-rec tag, game recommendation question are off topic for this site. Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. As Someone_Evil points out, we no longer allow game-recommendation questions; [this post on meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5747/33569) explains the reasoning why. As such, this question has been closed. Such questions might be better suited to a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go). Hope you stick around, and let us know if you have any questions!

Comment: Never fear though: there are lots of games like this, and you’ll get a variety of options if you do ask on a discussion forum!